# Different datestyle value for postgresql.conf file for same environment

Tags: postgresql, debian

G'Day,

I was setting up a new machine today with an environment identical to the other developer machines and I installed postgreSQL using a debian package. After more than an hour's worth of troubleshooting I found that our application kept crashing on the new machine because it's datestyle value in postgresql.conf was set to 'ISO, MDY' whereas on the old machines it was 'ISO, DMY'. I checked the values of @LC_TIME@ (in fact all `locale` values) and they're the same across the machines. Any idea what could've caused this difference in the setting?

Thanks!

Comment: What distro do the development machines run?

Comment: This is not an answer, but an application crashing because of a different datestyle is an application that needs fixing.

Comment: @Mike Development machines use Debian Lenny

Comment: @leonbloy Considering we store the dates in the database in a particular format and then our development environment sets up PostgreSQL so its `datestyle` also has the same format, our queries expect `<<some substring of xml>>::date` to work. When the datestyle is off, it cannot parse the date and the database gives an error. Not the most robust way to do things, I agree.

Comment: @GauravDadhania: it's not robuts, indeed, to cast from/to varchar-date relying on the datestyle. Postgresql provides functions to do these conversions, specifying the format.

Comment: @leonbloy Even if you do use those date conversion functions, you're assuming the initial value to be in a particular format, and it will still not work correctly, if your assumed initial format is not what you expected, right? (Unless you can have a stored procedure and check different formats using exceptions?)

Comment: @GauravDadhania: where does that 'initial value' comes from? the datestyle only affects (in an application) conversion from/to date/string using plain casts (`::date`), and an application can always (and should always) avoid those casts and use instead explicit conversions (with a explicit format defined in the application code, NOT in the postgresql configuration). The issue is analogous to that of conversion between bytes and strings (say, in Java): an application can (and shoould) avoid relying on defaults charsets.

Answer (score 0):

Two points, first if you send dates to PostgreSQL in yyyy-mm-dd format, datestyle is irrelevant.

The initial value comes from the postgresql.conf which is set up by the installation of the package (initdb or the rpm/deb/etc).  The best option here is to change it, but to correct your application to send dates to the db in yyyy-mm-dd format.